# Landau Critical Alpha exponent

Tags: statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

I have a problem on a property of the $\alpha$ exponent, defined as
$$C_V=T\frac{d^2L}{dT^2}\rightarrow^{t\to0^{\pm}}t^{-\alpha_\pm}$$
where $t=\frac{T-T_C}{T_C}$. From what I understood $\alpha_+=\alpha_-$ which is proven from the homogeneity of the Landau free energy L.
But with the example of $L(m)=-tm^2/2-cm^6$ I found that this is not true.
I found the minima of L m=0 for t>0 and $m=\pm(-t/6c)^{1/4}$ for t<0 then
$$L((-t/6c)^{1/4})=(-t)^{3/2}A$$
$$\frac{d}{dT}=\frac{d}{T_Cdt}$$
$$C_v\approx(-t)^{-1/2}\rightarrow\alpha_-=1/2$$
For $t\to0^+$ instead there is the m=0 minima which gives L=0 and $\alpha_+=0$
I'm doing something wrong or the equality between alphas holds only for particoular Ls?